# Prevent stack trace on failed connection

Tags: java, jdbc

In my DB connection, the stack trace for a failed connection is always printed to the terminal, is it possible to turn this off?

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + getHost() + ":" + getPort() + "/" + getDatabase(), getUser(), getPassword());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // deal with exception
}
```

I currently have the local DB turned off so it will always time out and try to catch the exception.

Example output looks like:

```
    Sep 21, 2018 2:07:56 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at database.psql.PsqlDatabase.connect(PsqlDatabase.java:41)
    at database.DatabaseFactory.getDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:15)
    at api.acme.AcmeApi.queuePlacementNotifications(AcmeApi.java:101)
    at poller.AcmePoller.run(AcmePoller.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:156)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: @ernest_k I've edited the question to reflect the full stack.

Comment: Looks like is the jdbc driver that's printing the stack trace. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028036/how-do-i-log-postgres-driver-messages-with-slf4j

Comment: Another option is to provide a feature toggle (environment variable, main argument, etc.) to bypass attempting to create the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of pgjdbc, in class **org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl** it was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/30f06e1411373d72ab59debc352ddf746f6812da#diff-05d8a51055f6afe0ae5176e0e5574cb0).

And this fix was released on version [42.2.3](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html#version_42.2.3).

So, if you can update your pgjdbc library, application will show logs only if Logger is configured to FINE level.

Comment: That's exactly what I looking for, my version was at 42.2.2, I can actually skip ahead to the latest.