# How to Grant Elevated Permissions to JMeter on MacOS so the JDBC Driver Can Load the Default Properties?

Tags: postgresql, macos, jmeter

I am running JMeter 5.6.2 on MacOS in GUI mode to create a JDBC load test.  Attempting to use the database sampler to connect to Postgres results in the exception:

> Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of
> class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL

I stepped through the code and the problem arises when org.postgresql.Driver attempts to gain privileged access to load its default configuration.

```
   this.defaultProperties = (Properties)doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Properties>() {
       public Properties run() throws IOException {
           return Driver.this.loadDefaultProperties();
       }
   });
```

Is there a way to grant JMeter elevated privileges on MacOS or is there a workaround for providing the default configuration to the JDBC Postgres driver?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help you without seeing the full stacktrace or even better full [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file preferably [with debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for JMeter's JDBC Test Elements and [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028036/how-do-i-log-postgres-driver-messages-with-slf4j/43242672#43242672)

The Postgres instance I'm using is [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) with the ID of `c2a319b219d08828d37097851901a94e04f9c79f163ee0ee8f112f24a95dda73`. The driver is [latest as of now 42.6.0 for Java 8](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/). You can try pulling and running the image and connecting to it, if it will be successful something is wrong with your Postgres instance and you will need to check its logs, configuration or contact your DBA